# Best way to get the same weekly flights at discount

Tags: air-travel

I am going to be travelling between DTW and LGA on a weekly basis at the same time each week and want to book my flights in bulk. Is there a good way to exploit travel benefits to do this at a discount? Or is there any service that does this?

Comment: [Here's the same question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7106/what-is-the-cheapest-way-to-get-tickets-for-weekly-scheduled-flights?rq=1) from almost twelve years ago. The discussion and suggestions may be useful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the cheapest way to get tickets for weekly scheduled flights?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7106/what-is-the-cheapest-way-to-get-tickets-for-weekly-scheduled-flights)

Comment: @hkotsubo That answer recommends Delta, but it's for a specific route (MSP-PHX) that doesn't match this one.

Comment: For each direction, what day of the week and which approximate time? The usual suspects like Friday afternoon/evening are usually more expensive than the others. Is LGA is requirement? Is a non-stop a requirement?

Comment: I'm amazed that Spirit usually sells this for $26 up to mid-May (not on Fridays of course) and then it goes up to >$300. I suppose they haven't loaded all fares yet.

Comment: You should call the airline (sales department). Such things often are done ad-hoc. I assume they do not need too many booked flights (Not all tour operators and travel agents are huge). Or pay a travel agent to do this for you (so ev. also extra discount from agent fees).

Comment: How difficult would it be to drive? It appears to be just under 1000 km though, which I can understand would be not feasible for many despite the fact that you'll most likely be on highways during that time. Driving assistance tools (such as adaptive cruse control) would be useful.

Edit: Assuming a petrol price of $1/L and a car with a fuel economy of 10 km/L, that would mean a cost of $100 each way, which is more than I thought...

Comment: @Leaderboard it's amusing seeing non-Americans suggest "just drive!". It can take more time to drive across one US state than an entire European country... Flying DFW-LGA may take 6 hours including the drive to/from the airports, but the drive between the two is 9 hours. Plus traffic, food & gas stops. That's exhausting at the end of a long week of work. OP would spend Sunday driving DTW->LGA, work all week, then spend Saturday driving LGA->DTW.  He'd have a few hours in DTW to spend with family/friends and probably spend most of that time sleeping...

Comment: @FreeMan if driving takes 9 hours, surely there has to be a decent high-speed train that takes less than half that, right?

Comment: If FreeMan's interpretation of this as weekly commute is right, in which sort of world are we living that this makes more sense than moving closer to work, or finding a job closer to home?

Comment: @Leaderboard considering US low-speed highways, any reasonably efficient modern car would do 5L/100km, or 20km/L

Comment: @njzk2 it's the US though... and I thought many US cars are high-powered - don't think you'd get 20 km/L on highway. For example, our Jeep Grand Cherokee can get about ~8-9 km/l overall on a highway-heavy trip (also I think most US highways have speed limit of at least 113 km/h - not *that* low). I thought it was something to do with work on why the OP had to make such frequent trips, but could be wrong. And it's the US, so most of the country wouldn't have rail as a viable alternative.

Comment: We're Americans, @njzk2, what is this "high speed rail" of which you speak? To be fair, there is _some_ _somewhat_ high-speed rail along the Eastern Seaboard (roughly Boston to Washington, DC, maybe further south), but definitely _not_ cross-country. There's no stomach for paying for it here, and the distances are _vastly_ greater than most Europeans realize. The record speed for driving NYC -> LA was just over 32 hours (been reduced a bit) for more than 3,000 miles at _exceedingly extra-legal_ speeds. How European countries would you traverse in 32 hours at the posted limit?

Comment: @FreeMan we're not talking about NYC-LA, we're talking about Detroit to New York, which is about 1000km, or the distance between Lille and Marseille. This takes 5 hours, being conservative about the station change in Paris.

Comment: @FreeMan (are we playing who has the biggest country?)

Comment: No, but so many people say "can't you drive - it's only 2 states" (I've had personal experience with this) when they really have no idea of just how big the US is.

Comment: @FreeMan I wouldn't wish on anyone to have to drive 1000km twice a week. And I think flying twice a week is also un-reasonable, and the OP should move next to their job or find a job closer to home. But, if travelling so much is the only way, I'd much rather do that in a fast train, and avoid having to get to and from an airport

Answer (score 3):

#### DISCLAIMER: airlines *may* not like this

Based on experience of coworkers who were doing this 15+ years ago, you may get banned or loose tickets for doing this. You have been warned...

---

I have heard that some people who have to travel weekly like this will book pairs of overlapping round-trip tickets.

Assuming:

- A) DTW-LGA on day 1, week 1
- B) LGA-DTW on day 5, week 1
- C) DTW-LGA on day 1, week 2
- D) LGA-DTW on day 5, week 2

Book:

- Round trip A-D
- Round trip B-C

Both trips involve staying over a weekend which *usually* gives you lower rates as it's assumed to *not* be travel for business.

If you know you're going to be doing this for *several* months, you could even extend the cycle:

Assuming:

- A) DTW-LGA on day 1, week 1
- B) LGA-DTW on day 5, week 1
- C) DTW-LGA on day 1, week 2
- D) LGA-DTW on day 5, week 2
- E) DTW-LGA on day 1, week 3
- F) LGA-DTW on day 5, week 3

Book:

- Round trip A-D
- Round trip B-E
- Round trip C-F

If you book all the flights on *one* airline, someone (or some technology) might notice and you could end up loosing flights.

If you pick two airlines (Delta for the DTW-LGA-DTW pairs and United for the LGA-DTW-LGA pairs, as an example), it would be much more difficult for them to suss this out. To each airline, you're simply making one round trip every few weeks and spending 2 weeks at the destination.

Depending on exactly how the schedule works out, you may need a one-week round-trip pair at the end to get you back to DTW at the end of the cycle, and that'll cost more, but you'll have saved over the long run.

In the good ol' days, it would have been difficult to keep track of all the paper tickets and make sure you were using the right one at the right time. In today's electronic world, it should be pretty straight forward to keep the flight details in your calendar and/or flight tracker and use the airline's apps to keep and access the next flight coupon in the proper order.

Note that there is no specific service or discount for doing this, however, the length of stay in each round trip pair will, generally, get you lower ticket pricing because you seem to be a tourist, not a business traveler. The airlines presume that business travel is paid for by the company so they charge them more.

Comment: I think airlines are actually OK with this, or at least recognize there is not much they can do about it - unlike other tricks like hidden city ticketing you aren't violating the terms of the tickets.

Comment: fair enough, @DJClayworth. I knew some people who were doing this 15-20 years ago. They were concerned about getting "caught". Might have been because they were using one airline and not splitting across multiple. IIRC, one person did have flights cancelled when it was discovered. :shrug: I've got a disclaimer, just in case.

Comment: Updated to indicate the time frame of potential ticket loss.

Comment: Read the terms in the conditions of carriage carefully here. If you're doing this with just one airline, in order to circumvent fare rules then they won't be impressed if they realise you're doing this and will try to enforce provisions of the terms you don't like. The advice to book it using 2 or 3 different airlines is wise.

Comment: That's why this answer starts with a great big disclaimer, @Flexo.

Answer (score 2):

This depends a bit on your specific details and constraints. The only US airline that currently offers "all you can fly" passes is Frontier but they don't operate on that route. Best you can do here is probably to maximize frequent flyer benefits, but even that won't amount to much since the airlines have aggressively devalued their programs over the last few years and the still chipping away at them.

If you want to fly non-stop your options are Delta, American and Spirit. Spirit is typically the lowest bidder: but you get what you pay for !

Delta seems to be cheaper than American, and you should be able to get a roundtrip economy ticket for abut $200 basic or $250 main cabin, especially if you interleave them.

Assuming you fly 40 round trips/year this comes out to be $10000 in spent and 40,000 miles flown. So for Delta you'll barely make it do Gold Medallion, which really isn't anything to write home about.

At a spend of $10000/year, the airline will not give you any discounts or special treatments. Things are different if you fly paid business on a regular basis, so it all depends on the details